# Use Reflection to new a webdriver class

Tags: c#, reflection, selenium, webdriver

I want to use reflection to  new a webdriver class.

My code like this:

```
<i>public static IWebDriver driver;</i>

<i>driver = (IWebDriver)Assembly.Load("OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox").CreateInstance("OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver");</i>
```

but it fail. the driver show nothing and the value is null.

Is it the location `OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox` wrong?

Comment: Is there a reason you're using late binding? Can you not simply add a reference to the assembly and instantiate the class directly?

Comment: the reason why i use this cus I want to change the driver by a string.Like:  string a = firfoxDriver . I can use [ "OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox."+a ] replace the string in the creatinstance field.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a switch such as:

```
        IWebDriver driver;

        switch (BrowserType)
        {
            case "Firefox":
                driver = new FirefoxDriver();
                break;
            case "IE":
                driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(HomeUrl);
```

Comment: this is the way I use it, but my boss said he hopes me not to use switch or if else to do  tihs.

Comment: You could just use a config file and set "BrowserType" in that. This is actually what I do, then use the switch to create the right driver. I am not sure why he/she is against a switch, could you provide a reason?

Comment: He just say the complexity is too high.

Comment: The Big O complexity? The Big O for a switch (in C#) is just O(n), so if you have 3 browsers it is 3 (not exactly a scary number :P). Any other work around will involve more work, which in turn will be as slow if not slower. Maybe someone else has another option for you though, but I feel like they are being a little too pedantic.

Comment: He's probably referring to the [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) of the resulting method. Static analysis like FxCop will bark about that sort of pattern every time. The unit tests for the .NET bindings in the WebDriver project itself use reflection to instantiate the driver, so this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to do this. I think in your example code above, you're using the namespace in which the class is present, not the name of the assembly. Here is a routine based loosely on what's done by the unit tests in the Selenium project itself.

```
// Note that assemblyName should normally be "WebDriver". It's provided
// as an argument here just in case there's a third-party driver
// implementation for a browser not supported by the core project.
// driverClassName should be something like "OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver"
public IWebDriver CreateDriver(string assemblyName, driverClassName)
{
    // TODO: Handle argument validation and exception handling
    // for error conditions.
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(assemblyName);
    Type driverType = assembly.GetType(driverClassName);
    return (IWebDriver)Activator.CreateInstance(driverType);
}
```